# Loading different Resource Dictionaries for different screen resolutions

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a Resource Dictionary in which I have defined styles and control templates for my application. Now I want to define more Resource Dictionaries to target different screen resolutions, one for each screen resolution. How can I detect client screen resolution and load particular Resource Dictionary in App.XAML?

**My Current App.XAML:**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\BlueYellow\BlueYellowTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Honestly, i wouldn't do that. WPF renders all with Vectors and has some very nice layouting. There should be very little dependant on the resolution. But thats just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks dowhilefor. Actually i am using images in my button controls. If image resolution is 72x72 then buttons looks ugly on lower screen resolutions. I want to use 48x48 or 32x32 image resolutions for that resolutions.

Comment: Ok, with images it makes kind of sense. But you could query these images from code. We use a system that stores images internally with a key and we wrote a MarkupExtension to call it like Image="{Stock SaveIcon, Size=64}" something similar might help you too. And of course you can modify the App.xaml directly in code aswell. using Application.Resources in c# code.

Comment: In the application I'm currently working on (touch screen) it's simply not possible to scale things to fit all supported screen resolutions and so switching to a totally new view depending on resolution is a valid request I think, it gives the users the richest possible display for them.

Comment: My application is also touch screen thats why i m trying to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make markupExtension, which returns appropriate resource dictionary uri depending on resolution and use it like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="{ThemeUriAccordingToCurrentResolution}" />
```

Comment: You mean to say while loading Resource Dictionary Source attribute it will call that extension in which I should first check the resolution and then send appropriate URI

Answer (score 1):

I can see the value in being able to switch resources based on screen resolution, you'll obviously have to do some work to bring the vast number of resolutions down into a manageable short list and find the "best fit" for the current one but here you go.

App.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  // Get the width and height, you might want to at least round these to a few values.
  var width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
  var height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

  // make the resource path from them.
  string resourceName = string.Format("Themes\resource{0}x{1}", width, height);

  // Add the resource to the app.
  Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(resourceName, UriKind.Relative)));

  base.OnStartup(e);
}
```